# How to check if ListView scrolled to the end?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have service for get data from json. Service is a task that also has parameters (`int page int pageSize`).

I have a view model that call service and where from I send parameters page and page size...

When page is opened, service should show only 10 first result and when listView is scroll to the bottom should show next 10 results and so on...

So, the point is how to recall function when ListView is on bottom?

Comment: I've not used this library myself but they use a trick with a footer element here: https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-use-continuous-or-infinite-scrolling-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: And also there is a youtube video guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DG5Asglf0vU

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058265/how-to-detect-hitting-the-bottom-of-a-grid-within-a-scrollview-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

You can check the items appearing and then call a Load method to add more elements:

```
listview.ItemAppearing += (sender, e) => 
            {
                if(isLoading || Items.Count == 0)
                    return;

                //hit bottom!
                if(e.Item.ToString() == Items[Items.Count - 1])
                {
                    LoadItems();
                }
            };
```