# Move the button at the end of list view - Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I'm looking to relocate a button within my code to the conclusion of a list view. At present, the button is constantly visible, but my aim is for it to become visible only when the user scrolls to the list view's end. Could you guide me on how to achieve this?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:XXX.XXX.ExternalDisplay.App.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:XXX.XXX.ExternalDisplay.App.Converters"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:XXX.XXX.ExternalDisplay.Core.Models;assembly=XXX.XXX.ExternalDisplay.Core"
             x:Class="XXX.XXX.ExternalDisplay.App.Views.Checklist"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:DataType="viewModels:ChecklistViewModel"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BlackBackgroundColor}">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <xct:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter" />
        <converters:CheckedColorConverter x:Key="CheckedColorConverter" />
        <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout Padding="5">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MenuBackgroundColor}" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto" Padding="8" MinimumHeightRequest="20">
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Sina" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Checklist" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="Truck" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ChecklistSections}" HasUnevenRows="True"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ChecklistSection">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5">
                            <Label Text="{Binding ChecklistCategory.Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="5,0,0,0" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" />

                            <Frame CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="White" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BlackBackgroundColor}" HasShadow="True" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0">
                                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ChecklistItems}" Padding="5">
                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ChecklistItem">
                                            <StackLayout Padding="5" Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemText}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" Color="Green" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" Color="Red" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <Editor IsVisible="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
                                                        Placeholder="Comments" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MenuBackgroundColor}" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
    
    <Button Text="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WarningBackgroundColor}" BorderRadius="10" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216281/how-to-check-is-listview-scrolled-to-the-end

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

> At present, the button is constantly visible, but my aim is for it to become visible only when the user scrolls to the list view's end. Could you guide me on how to achieve this?

You can put the button into `ListView.Footer`. Like this:

```xml
        .....
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Footer>
        <Button Text="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WarningBackgroundColor}" BorderRadius="10" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

It can achieve your need. For more info you can refer to [Headers and footers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#headers-and-footers).